# Image Tag Not to submit with form Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using CK Editor WYSIWYG OK so when the admin comes on the page it will display the image in text area from database  so when he updates text area and then submit then the image tag is also submitting i want to stop it.
Means i want image tag just read-only/disabled

```
<textarea name="editor2" id="editor2" rows="1000" cols="80">
<?php echo $event_details_db;?>
<?php if ($event_image_path_db != '' ) { ?>
<img src="uploads/events/<?php echo ($event_image_path_db); ?>">
<?php } ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: image tag can't be disabled. Yet you have not posted the form and javascript used to submit the text area values.

Comment: @Jai not entirely true, can remove image and view source controls from toolbar which is my suggestion on how to resolve this.

Comment: @charlietfl how?? kindly help me

Comment: read the CK Editor toolbar configuration docs. Will take some more advanced scripting to prevent delete of image though. SHould be able to in the API I think